# Variables not initialized in ActionListener

Tags: java, awt, actionlistener

I am trying to have this program print the topping and crust selected, the way it is set up now, it only prints the name. I tried initializing all the strings to be empty strings "". But no matter what button was clicked, the string was always empty even though the if statments are suppsed to change them.

Here is the code

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource() == output){    
        String str2, str3, str4, str5;
        String str1 = txtName.getText();
        if(e.getSource() == optThick){
            str2  = "thick crust";
        }
        else if (e.getSource() == optThin){
             str2 = "thin crust ";
        }
        if(e.getSource() == cbCheese){
            str3 = "Cheese ";
        }
        if(e.getSource() == cbOlives){
             str4 = "Olives ";
        }
        if(e.getSource() == cbTomatoes){
             str5 = "Tomatoes ";
        }

        textArea.setText("Name : " + str1 + "\n" + "Crust: " + str2 + "\n" + "Toppings: " + str3 + str4 + str5); 
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What's behind "optThick" and these variables? If you compare them like "==" you maybe just compare the object which might ofc fail. What did a debugger say?

Comment: Variables str2, str3, str4 and str5 may not have been initialized

Answer (score 1):

```
if(e.getSource() == output){    
       // code omitted 
}
```

All of your if statements are inside the outer statement. Is that it ?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone was wondering, this is how I got it to work.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource() == output){    
        String str2 = "", str3 = "", str4 = "", str5 = "";
        String str1 = txtName.getText();
        if(optThick.isSelected()){
            str2  = "Thick crust";
        }
        else if (optThin.isSelected()){
             str2 = "Thin crust ";
        }
        if(cbCheese.isSelected()){
            str3 = "Cheese ";
        }
        if(cbOlives.isSelected()){
             str4 = "Olives ";
        }
        if(cbTomatoes.isSelected()){
             str5 = "Tomatoes ";
        }

        textArea.setText(String.format("Name: %s \nCrust: %s\n Toppings: %s%s%s ",str1, str2, str3, str4, str5)); 
    }
}
```